# Recent rows for each id

Tags: mysql

I have a below table and I need most recent rows for each id.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id    Station_id      lastupdate       hrl_abst daily_abst Water_Level
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3      Pump15    2014-05-13 12:45:00    23            45      8
4      Pump0     2014-05-20 01:01:00    1             1       1
5      Pump0     2014-07-02 12:00:00    15.41      15.41     51.95
6      Pump0     2014-07-03 12:00:00    0.9         21.6     26.65
7      Pump1     2014-07-03 01:30:00    0            0       21.69
8      Pump0     2014-07-05 09:20:00    20           20      26.7535
9      Pump1     2014-07-05 11:25:00    20           20      21.69
10     Pump2     2014-07-05 15:10:00    20           20      9.4287
11     Pump3     2014-07-05 15:45:00    20           20      6.2608
12     Pump4     2014-07-05 13:25:00    20           20      2.2636
13     Pump5     2014-07-05 16:31:00    20           20      2.2832
14     Pump6     2014-07-05 16:38:00    20           20      2.1249
15     Pump7     2014-07-05 17:35:00    20           20      10
16     Pump8     2014-07-05 17:35:00    20           20      10
17     Pump9     2014-07-05 19:36:00    20           20      2.0994
18     Pump10    2014-07-05 19:55:00    20           20      2.112
19     Pump11    2014-07-05 20:15:00    20           20      2.1054
20     Pump12    2014-07-05 19:45:00    20           20      2.099
21     Pump13    2014-07-05 18:45:00    20           20      2.0994
22     Pump14    2014-07-05 16:45:00    20           20      10
23     Pump15    2014-07-05 16:45:00    20           20      2.1234
24     Pump16    2014-07-05 19:45:00    20           20      10
25     Pump17    2014-07-05 18:25:00    20           20      52.5678
26     Pump18    2014-07-05 18:50:00    20           20      42.0116
27     Pump19    2014-07-05 14:20:00    20           20      10
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I used below query but it is not working.

```
 select * from sgwebdb.pump_station_data
  where id in  (
  select max(id) from sgwebdb.pump_station_data group by Station_id
   )
 order by Station_id;
```

Comment: show your sample output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT *
FROM sgwebdb.pump_station_data t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Station_id,  MAX(lastupdate) as lastupdate
  FROM sgwebdb.pump_station_data
  GROUP BY Station_id
) t2
  ON t1.Station_id = t2.Station_id
  AND t1.lastupdate = t2.lastupdate
```

Comment: bro I am getting version error with your query "Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' 0.031 sec
"

Comment: it is giving same result what my query is giving :) .last update column is showing recent date time but respective rows are not recent , like daily abstraction and hourly abstraction data are not showing recent one

Comment: I think finally it fixed ,try it now :)

Comment: it is fixed now.Thanks a ton

Comment: can we join your query with this query ?select
     SD.id,SD.Scenario,PR.Type,PR.StationName,max(if(PARAM = 'minH', Value, ' ')) as 'minH',max(if(PARAM = 'maxH', Value, ' ')) as 'maxH',psd.Station_Id,psd.Min_OL,
  psd.Max_OL
 from
     sgwebdb.param_reference as PR
         Inner join
     sgwebdb.scenario_data as SD ON PR.Param_Id = SD.Param_Id
         INNER JOIN
     sgwebdb.qualicision_detail as Q ON SD.SCENARIO = Q.Alternative
         INNER JOIN
     sgwebdb.pump_station_detail as psd ON psd.Station_Id = PR.Station_Id
 where
     PR.Type = 'Pump' and Q.Alternative = 'C'
 GROUP BY PR.Id;

Comment: do you want to replace  `sgwebdb.pump_station_detail` with the `query in answer`??.if so then update your query by replacing  `sgwebdb.pump_station_detail` with `( query in answer ) as psd `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60512/discussion-between-vikrant-singh-and-vim).

Answer (score 0):

You need to select only id not max id in sub-query

```
 select * from pump_station_data
where id in (
select id from pump_station_data group by Station_id order by lastupdate desc
)
```

Here is [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13756/10)

Comment: I need to fetch most recent rows for each id , your query is not giving most recent rows for each id

Answer (score 0):

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM sgwebdb.pump_station_data 
ORDER BY `lastupdate` DESC, `id` DESC 
GROUP BY `Station_id`
```

This will give you order by the latest id with the latest 'lastupdate'

Comment: you can not use select * with group by function.